# Update button text while doing an ajax call

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to update a button text while doing an ajax call (waiting for a result)?
I would like to show the user something is/has happened?

```
<button onclick="Validate()" type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="validateButton"><i class="fas fa-shield-check"></i> Check</button>

function Validate() {
$("#validateButton").html('<i class="fas fa-spinner"></i> Checking');
    //jquery stuff
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Client/Validate',
            async: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: { model: JSON.stringify(model) },
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                $('#chkDateResults').html(data);

            }
            
        });

        }

        $("#validateButton").html('<i class="fas fa-shield-check"></i> Re-Check');

    }
```

So only this seems to work

```
$("#validateButton").html('<i class="fas fa-shield-check"></i> Re-Check');
```

I never see this `$("#validateButton").html('<i class="fas fa-spinner"></i> Checking');`

even if I hold the thread for 5 seconds, ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using `async: false`, you are *blocking* the browser from doing anything else (including screen repainting) until the request finishes; it has no chance to display the `Checking` text until the request finishes.

Change to `async: true`, and put everything that depends on the response finishing in the `success` callback.

```
success: function(data) {
  $('#chkDateResults').html(data);
  $("#validateButton").html('<i class="fas fa-shield-check"></i> Re-Check');
}
```